# How to enable external rendering engine?

Tags: rendering, add-on, external-applications

I've been using Blender for about a year now, and have never been successful at enabling any external rendering add-on. I end up with the message below whenever I attempt to do so. Do I need to the have actual, separate rendering engine installed before enabling the add-on?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Strictly speaking, this is off-topic since the plugin you are using should tell you how to install it. The error you are receiving is telling me that the plugin expects a file at "C:\Progam Files\Pixar" though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all external renderers are separate applications to Blender. The addons are simply helper scripts to pass data back and forth between Blender and the app. You definitely need to have the renderer application installed on your computer to get it to work.